# Include Parentheses () in the Template literals?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to include Parentheses `()` in the string when using Template literals?

Currently its output:

```
Test Yes Test
```

I expect to output like this with the parentheses:

```
Test (Yes) Test
```

Code:

```
let type = "Yes";
let string = `Test ${type? (type) : ''} Test`;
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use template in the template

```js
const type = 'yes';
const string = `Test ${type? `(${type})` : ``} Test`;

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the entire `placeholder`:

```js
let type = 'yes';
let string = `Test (${type? type : ''}) Test`;

console.log(string)
```

Or if you need to not include it if type is falsy then you can concat them with `+` or use a nested placeholder:

```js
let type = 'Yes';
let string = `Test ${type ? `(${type})` : ''} Test`;

console.log(string)
```

And just for fun you can write a [Tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) to make it more reusable:

```js
function myTag(strings, ...values) {
  let result = '';
  strings.forEach((string, i) => {
    // strings will always be +1 length over values as per the spec
    const value = values[i] ? `(${values[i]})` : ''
    result += string + value;
  });
  return result;
}

const test1 = "Yes";
const result1 = myTag`Test ${test1} Test`;
console.log(result1);

const test2 = null;
const result2 = myTag`Test ${test2} Test`;
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: () should not be included if `type` is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the parenthesis are part of the string and not just order of operations.

`` let string = `Test ${type? "(" + type + ")" : ''} Test`; ``